# Prove or disprove. The vertices of every regular tetrahedron in 3-space have at least two irrational coordinates.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, simplex

> Prove or disprove. All four vertices of every regular tetrahedron in $ \mathbb{R}^3$ have at least two irrational coordinates.

[image]

This question arose from my inability to construct a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with all the coordinates 
$$
M_x,M_y,M_z,N_x,N_y,N_z,P_x,P_y,P_z,Q_x,Q_y \;\mathrm
{and}\; Q_z,
$$
of its vertices $M$, $N$, $P$ and $Q$ being rational numbers.

Comment: Think about the tetrahedra in the cube.

Comment: This question answers yours. It's also Lord Shark's comment and @ParclyTaxel 's deleted answer.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423014/the-smallest-8-cubes-to-cover-a-regular-tetrahedron

Comment: You may want to think more carefully about the order of quantifiers in your question. As stated, the obvious interpretation is "For every tetrahedron $T \subset \mathbb R^3$, and for ever vertex $V = (V_x,V_y,V_z)$ of $T$, at least two of the three coordinates $V_x,V_y,V_z$ are irrational", and it is way too easy to construct a counterexample to that statement as the answer of @RossMillikan shows.

Answer (score 3):

Choose four suitable vertices of the unit cube $[0,1]^3$, and you have a regular tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1):

You can place one of the vertices at the origin.  A second one can be at $(1,0,0)$

Comment: I wouldn't put my second vertex there....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:  The question claimed that every point had two irrational coordinates.  I have two points with no irrational coordinates which disproves the assertion.  I saw your comment indicating that we can do it with no irrational coordinates.

Comment: Also, the first sentence alone suffices, I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to prove that there doesn't exist a regular tetrahedron such that all its vertices have only rational coordinates. Assume the contrary, let $ABCD$ be such a tetrahedron. Consider the plane $(ABC)$ as a complex plane with origin in $A$ and let the points $B$ and $C$ have associated complex numbers $a+bi$ and $c+di$. By our assumption, we would have that $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$. We know that the points associated to complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ form an equilateral triangle if and only if $z_1+\varepsilon z_2+\varepsilon^2z_3=0$ where $\varepsilon=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ is the root of order 3 of the unity. By plugging our numbers, we obtain
$$a+bi+\varepsilon(c+di)+\varepsilon^2\cdot 0=0\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow a+bi+\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)(c+di)=0\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow a+bi-\frac{c}{2}-\frac{d}{2}i+\frac{\sqrt{3}c}{2}i-\frac{\sqrt{3}d}{2}=0\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow a-\frac{c}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}d}{2}=0\Rightarrow d=0$$
also
$$b-\frac{d}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}c}{2}=0\Rightarrow c=0$$
thus $A=C$, so we don't actually have a triangle $ABC$ hence the conclusion.

Comment: This is a correct proof about equilateral triangles in the plane. But in space you can build an equilateral triangle with all rational coordinates - the normal to its plane will have some irrationality. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

False.

Proof.
Here is one possible solution:

- vertex 1: (1 0 0)
- vertex 2: (0 0 1)
- vertex 3: (0 1 0)
- vertex 4: (1 1 1)

You can check that:

- all coordinates of all vertices are rational;
- and that all distances from one vertex to another are equal (thus this is a regular tetrahedron).